# Use field values inside a Where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently developing some Quality Checks for a database and we have a table that lists out which columns are Required fields. My question is, would it be possible to use this table to generate a where...is null statement? Example below

```
select * from Required_Fields_Table
inner join Transaction_Table
on key fields
where (value inside field) is null
```

Thanks!

edit: this is using Microsoft SQL Server

More Details: 
We have a Transactions table, and whether a field in that table is required is different based on the type of user (new, active, pending, etc). We have a table that maps these requirements out (a record for each field/status combination). I was hoping to use that table to run a check to make sure we weren't missing required information.

Comment: Yes, this might work.  Can you show us some sample data?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Horse!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but hopefully this will heap... you can use this query to get a list of tables and all fields that are nullable

```
select o.name TableName, c.name ColumnName
from sys.objects o
inner join sys.columns c on o.object_id = c.object_id
where c.is_nullable = 1 -- 1 for nullable, 0 for not nullable
and o.type = 'u' -- user table
and o.name = '{insert table name here if you wish to refine your search}'
```

From there you can build up queries for each table with the help of a cursor

Comment: How do you know which database product Andrew is using?

Comment: He tagged it with SQL, so I assumed SQL Server, but who knows.  Just trying to help Andrew out with the little information I have

Comment: Thanks for the response fellow Andrew! 

So, I definitely didn't provide enough information in the question. In this case we have a Transactions table, and whether a field in that table is required is different based on the type of user (new, active, pending, etc). We have a table that maps these requirements out (a record for each field/status combination). I was hoping to use that table to run a check to make sure we weren't missing required information.

Comment: You may not have noticed, but you still have not provided enough information. Please edit your question with this information, _and_ shoe table definitions and sample input and output data